# Access Snowflake query results through PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to access the results of a snowflake query in PowerBI directly or would I need to insert the results into a table.

Comment: Why not create a View in Snowflake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a View using a Select statement: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html

CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] [ SECURE ] [ RECURSIVE ] VIEW [ IF NOT EXISTS ] 
[ ( <column_list> ) ]
[ COPY GRANTS ]
[ COMMENT = '<string_literal>' ]
AS <select_statement>

Comment: Thanks! Would this view be available if I try to access it through PowerBI a week later? In its documents Snowflake mentions "A non-materialized view’s results are created by executing the query at the time that the view is referenced in a query. The results are not stored for future use"

Comment: Every time you access a View, the query it is based on is executed

Answer (score 0):

I dont have snowflake to test, but in powerbi you have under database datasource "snowflake".

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This does give me access to the tables stored in Snowflake but not to the results of the queries that I run in Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

Best option would be create view on the snowflake results query and use the view in PowerBI either in ImportMode or DirectQuery.

Comment: Hi! According to Snowflake documentation, it has 2 types of views- Non-materialized Views and Materialized Views. As it describes, “A non-materialized view’s results are created by executing the query at the time that the view is referenced in a query. The results are not stored for future use”. Materialised views are supported only by Enterprise Edition and I have a Standard Edition. Any other way I may be able to create a view?

Comment: Create a non-materialized view. Use PowerBI import mode option and select the newly created view. Only during first time or refreshing as per the schedule, PowerBI service uses Snowflake object to get the results into pbix file and saves in the power BI server. This way you get results faster and reduces networking

Answer (score -1):

@jagadish: materialized views also similar to database tables ( it will occupy space)

Check temporary tables and give a try.